# How to HTTP Request in Swift 2.0 (Xcode 7.2)

Tags: xcode, swift, web-services, swift2

I am trying make a http request to a web service. It returns JSON data. And I am also want to parse this data. I am new at swift I try many ways but get nothing. Here is my service address:

```
http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mobileservice/login/firmcode/mailaddress/password/ip
```

I am try to call service on this uri template. How can I do can anybody help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A nice way for sending http request is alamofire. Although you can also send http without external library. Look at this code

```
func sendHttpRequests(data : Dictionary<String, AnyObject>)
{
 let url = NSURL ( string : "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mobileservice/login/firmcode/mailaddress/password/ip")!
    let request:NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL : url)

    //Data that you want to send
    let payload = "{r: typeRequest, e: object, p: anotherObject}"
    //js_object is the key that is configured in your server
    let bodyData = "{js_object:\(payload)}"
    //Setting httpMethod
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"

    request.HTTPBody = bodyData.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);


    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())
        {
            (response, data, error) in

            //If response code is 200 you send the request successfully         
            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let responseCode = httpResponse.statusCode
                print(responseCode)
            }
            do
            {
                let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)


                print("Json sent by server\(json)")

                if let value = json["myKey"] as? String
                {

                    print(value)
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                print(error)
            }


    }
}
```

Pay attention if json sent by server is a valid json 
Here is an example in php

```
<?php
$arr = array('myKey' => "ciao", 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4);

echo json_encode($arr);
?>
```

Comment: How can I call this method? I am calling this at viewDidLoad sendHttpRequests(data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>) what should data be?

Comment: Oh sorry data should be something equal to payload and call this method when you click on a button or also in viewDidLoad and pass in payload the request you want

Comment: can you be more clear I am so new at swift and don't now how to call a func

Comment: You can remove : "data: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>" and call this function just with : sendHttpRequest().
But this function always pass this generic payload :

 let payload = "{r: typeRequest, e: object, p: anotherObject}" 

If you want to pass for example username.text and password.text you can create a dictionary and pass this one as argument

Comment: Thank you so much you are awesome I am trying this but now it gives error: Missing argument how can I fix this.

Comment: One more thing I want to ask should I change something in info.plist file?

Comment: No you don't have to do any changes! I hope i could help you

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire

+

https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON

EX :

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx/mobileservice/login/firmcode/mailaddress/password/ip", parameters: nil)
     .responseJSON { response in
         print(response.request)  // original URL request
         print(response.response) // URL response
         print(response.data)     // server data
         print(response.result)   // result of response serialization

         if let res= response.result.value {
             print("JSON: \(JSON)")
             //Here you can parse the json with swiftyJSON
             let json = JSON(res)
             let name = json["name"].string
         }
     }
```

Comment: How can I import Alamofire to my project?(I don't how to import external libraries)

Comment: The only one solution is to follow the process described in the link below - but yes you'll have to add this external library :/ It will save you a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a third party framework like Alamofire, as Benobab says. It's also quite easy to use `NSURLSession` and an `NSURLSessionTask` to do this. `NSURLSession` has a method `sharedSession` that gives you a session that's already configured. Then you want to create an `NSURLSessionDataTask`. Take a look at the Xcode docs for more info.